# Missing Manage Users Page on fresh install of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Just installed jenkins from the Ubuntu repository. The version is 1.574

I opened my firewall and then hit the URL  http://:8080

I then expected to get the managed users page, but instead I am getting the login page. In fact it redirects to http://:8080/login?from=%2F

I also cannot see any manage users link anywhere?

Any one have any ideas?

This is on a fresh vps.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled the security in config.xml which allowed me to get to the manage jenkins page

```
<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go to http://JENKINURL/configureSecurity and select Security Realm/Jenkins’ own user database. It will ask you to go back to login page where you can find create new user option.